# My CPU Usgage is constant 100% (Xcode, using SwiftUI)

Tags: swift, swiftui

My SwiftUI App is extremly lagging and I have no Idea why. Even if I only compile this code, my CPU Power goes up to 100%, even if I dont touch anything:

```
@main
struct Order_Corner_V8App: App {

    var body: some Scene {
        return WindowGroup {
            TabView{
                Text("").tabItem {
                    Text("click")
                }
                Text("").tabItem {
                    Text("click")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need the TabView. I put my whole Files in an other new Project, the same thing happend again. Maybe its usefull to know that im working with Firebase.

I'm targeting iOS.

I've already watched to my App in 'Instruments', it only says that the problem is my main View.
Please help me.
[Here is some image that shows my CPU Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ddhi.png)

Thanks, Boothosh

Comment: What happens if you just have a simple view, ContentView, in your WindowGroup and then move the TabView inside the ContentView? Off-topic and out of curiosity, why have you made the app name anonymous in the screen shot?

Comment: Exactly the same :(

Comment: What platform are you targeting? iOS? macOS? Are you absolutely sure nothing else can trigger updates to your `App`? If you create a completely new project and only include the code that you have in your question, does the issue happen? You need to provide all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make your question on-topic. It seems like there's something else that's missing from your question and might be the culprit.

Comment: Do you have an Apple Watch? If so, turn your Apple Watch off on the device that was connected. There is a known issue in XCode right now where fetching Symbols from the Apple Watch causes issues. Alternatively, connect the device and go to the device manager and ensure your symbols are being fetched properly.

Comment: What's is your phone? I have exactly same issue on 12 mini

Comment: I have an iPhone 7 plus... But if you have the same issue that means it wasn't the fault of my App :) Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I got the solution: I tried the App on an other phone and everything works fine. I think this is an mistake of my phone, but I don't know what I can do against that.
Thanks, Boothosh

Answer (score 0):

1. In my case, I found Xcode `source control` caused the problem

[image]

2. To fix this problem `Xcode -> Preferences -> Source Control` uncheck `Enable Source control`.  Then restart Xcode, everything will be fine

[image]